# How to export association rules into excel file in rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer, data-export

I am using RapidMiner to extract association rules. I connect 'write excel' operator after 'create association rule' operator but I get an error. It said that it need example set as input. Any suggestions to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Write` operator will write any object to disk. You can choose to save it as XML so it's human readable.

The `Store` operator will store an object in the repository where it can be retrieved later using the `Retrieve` operator. The file is not intended to be human readable.